# Pyspark convert dataframe to time series data with 2-day lag

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe as following:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+------+
|page |group  |utc_date   |t     |
+-----+-------+-----------+------+
|    A|12     |2023-01-02 |0.55  |
|    A|12     |2023-01-03 |0.6   |
|    A|12     |2023-01-04 |1.97  |
|    A|12     |2023-01-05 |1.31  |
|    B|36     |2023-01-02 |0.09  |
|    B|36     |2023-01-03 |0.09  |
|    B|36     |2023-01-04 |0.09  |
|    B|36     |2023-01-05 |0.02  |
|    C|36     |2023-01-02 |0.09  |
|    C|36     |2023-01-03 |0.09  |
|    C|36     |2023-01-04 |0.09  |
|    C|36     |2023-01-05 |0.08  |
+-----+-------+-----------+------+
```

I wanna convert the dataframe into a time series dataset with 2-day lag (group by page and group):

```
+-----+-------+-----------+------+------+------+
|page |group  |utc_date   |t     |t-1   |t-2   |
+-----+-------+-----------+------+------+------+
|    A|12     |2023-01-02 |0.55  |null  |null  |
|    A|12     |2023-01-03 |0.6   |0.55  |null  |
|    A|12     |2023-01-04 |1.97  |0.6   |0.55  |
|    A|12     |2023-01-05 |1.31  |1.97  |0.6   |
|    B|36     |2023-01-02 |0.09  |null  |null  |
|    B|36     |2023-01-03 |0.09  |0.09  |null  |
|    B|36     |2023-01-04 |0.09  |0.09  |0.09  |
|    B|36     |2023-01-05 |0.02  |0.09  |0.09  |
|    C|36     |2023-01-02 |0.09  |null  |null  |
|    C|36     |2023-01-03 |0.09  |0.09  |null  |
|    C|36     |2023-01-04 |0.09  |0.09  |0.09  |
|    C|36     |2023-01-05 |0.08  |0.09  |0.09  |
+-----+-------+-----------+------+------+------+
```

How should I do it in pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `lag()` function on window group by page and group and ordered by date desc, so something like:

```py
window = Window.partitionBy("page", "group").orderBy("utc_date")
new_df = (
  df
  .withColumn("t-1", lag("t", 1).over(window))
  .withColumn("t-2", lag("t", 2).over(window))
)
```